# Bitfinex Api limit server or individual ip address

Tags: api, bitfinex

I'm using the Bitfinex API to create a website with prices of the cryptocurrencies on there. Their website says they have a 90 request limit per minute per ip address. Since I will be putting the website on a web server for everyone to access, will the limit be an individual ip address limit or server ip address limit?